# Evaluating $\int{(a^2-x^2)^n}dx$ using repeated integration by part

Tags: calculus, integration

The problem is as follows:

> Prove that
>   $$\int{(a^2-x^2)^n}dx=\frac{x(a^2-x^2)^n}{2n+1}+\frac{2a^2n}{2n+1}\int{(a^2-x^2)^{n-1}}dx+C$$ using integration by part.

I can easily obtain partially the first term, by making $dv=dx \Rightarrow v=x$, and $$u=(a^2-x^2)^n\Rightarrow du=(-2nx)(a^2-x^2)^{n-1}dx$$

But now it's hard to see a definite direction to go, so I also examined the equality needed to prove:

Multiplying both sides by $2n+1$ and subtracting both sides by $2n\int(a^2-x^2)^ndx$, I have a simpler form of equality I need to prove:
$$\int(a^2-x^2)^ndx =x(a^2-x^2)^n+2a^2n\int{(a^2-x^2)^{n-1}}dx-2n\int(a^2-x^2)^{n}dx$$

After this I tried a few approaches working toward it, I found none which presented any promising result. Feel free to throw some light upon my confusion.

Answer (score 2):

$$I_n=\int(a^2-x^2)^ndx=(a^2-x^2)^n\int dx-\int\left(\frac{d [(a^2-x^2)^n]}{dx}\int dx\right)dx$$

$$=x(a^2-x^2)^n-\int n(a^2-x^2)^{n-1} (-2x)xdx$$

$$=x(a^2-x^2)^n+2n\int (a^2-x^2)^{n-1} [a^2-(a^2-x^2)]dx$$

$$\implies I_n=x(a^2-x^2)^n+2na^2I_{n-1}-2nI_n$$

Comment: Aha I think you have misread my post, as the equation you are using is actually the simplified form of the equality I need to prove, i.e, I am trying to work toward this equality but just cannot get there!

Comment: @Eddy, Please find the edited version

Comment: Wow I see, I think I have tried this approach but must have computed something wrong along the way. Thank you very much!